# The name Process.Start does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, process

I'm a beginner programmer so I think I must be overlooking something simple, but after 2 hours of searching and even reinstalling Visual Studio I can't seem to fix this problem.

I need to start a 3rd party exe, so I need to use the Process class.

```
Process.Start(string)
```

However it gives a red line underneath and says: The name Process.Start does not exist in the current context. and The name Start does not exist in the current context.

These are the namespaces and I've referenced `System` and `System.Diagnostics.Tracing` also:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: Works for me... Which means you have left something out of your [mcve]

Comment: The class Process belongs to System.Diagnostics namespace which is already present and that compilation error should be gone. Just curious, why and how are you using "System.Diagnostics.Tracing" ?

Comment: Do you happen to have another type, property or method named `Process` in your your code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have put the **using System.Diagnostics;** directive inside a namespace and is calling **Process.Start()** from another namespace which does not contain that directive in it.

Could you share more of your code, perhaps?

Note: This would perhaps be more appropriate as a comment, but as a new contributor myself, I do not have enough reputation to add comments.